# LPX-00230: invalid character 0 (U+0000) found in a Name or Nmtoken

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltype

I receive:

- ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
- ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
- LPX-00230: invalid character 0 (U+0000) found in a Name or Nmtoken
- Error at line 2
- ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 254
- ORA-06512: at line 1

When attempting to execute:

```
select extractValue(
  XMLType(
    replace(myxmlcolumn,CHR(0),''
    )
  ), '/xpath/to/data'
)
foo,bar,foobar
from sch.tab 

WHERE cond='cond'
```

"myxmlcolumn" is of course a CLOB datatype, but contains XML.  This error would make sense if I wasn't doing the replace() on the NULL.  That and the error is intermittent (possibly do to the matching of my clauses).  How would a null be reported when it should have been replaced before the XML cast?

10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0, Toad for Oracle pro 10.6.1.3

edit:
- also tried replacing with 'H' to prove it wasn't inserting a NULL back in (same error)
- also tried replace(myxmlcolumn,'\n','' in case it didn't like the chr(0)  (same error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an elegant solution, and I feel a bit dirty.  From @jonearles answer it looks like a known bug.  The simple solution is to *NOT* even attempt to cast to XML.  Hopefully none of the advanced xpath was needed, in my case it was not.

```
Select dbms_lob.substr(myxmlcolumn, 10, dbms_lob.instr(myxmlcolumn,'<data>') + 6)
```

"data" was the element I was after, and it happens to always hold a value that is 10 long, and is the first and only occurrence of the element so... I got lucky.

Answer (score 2):

Search My Oracle Support for `LPX-00230`, this looks like Bug 9871430.

(I'd post more details but I don't think we're supposed to share information from that site.)

Comment: I don't suppose you can suggest any sort of *cough* workaround or at least the cause of the bug? Is there some sort of best-practice, or at least an "avoid doing this" blog about this that doesn't require an enterprise support contract? I'm just a simple contractor.

Comment: I guess I'll have to trust you enough to give you an upvote.  Sure wish I could see behind the curtain.